# Partial derivatives generalization

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $F:U\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$ be a function for some open $U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$. If all partial derivatives of $F$ exist and are continuous in a neighborhood of some point $x_0\in U$, then $F$ is differentiable at $x_0$.

Partial derivatives are the directional derivatives in the direction of the standard basis vectors of $\mathbb{R}^n$. I wondered if there is something special about partial derivatives as they seem to depend on the choice of this basis.
Is the statement still true if we choose a different basis?
Could the above statement be generalized in the following way?
Let $F:U\rightarrow W$ be a funtion where $U\subseteq V$ open and $V,W$ finite dimensional (real) Banach spaces. Also, let $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ be a basis for $V$. If the directional derivatives $\partial_{v_i}F$ exist for $i=1,\dots,n$ and are continuous in a neighbordhood of $x_0\in U$, then $F$ is differentiable in $x_0$.

Comment: What kind of vector spaces are $V$ and $W$? You mention open subsets and directional derivatives of maps $V \to W$, but in general we don't have enough structure to define such notions.

Comment: I added this to my post. I meant the notions of derivatives, open subsets etc. with respect to any norm on these (real) vector spaces.

Comment: One may talk about derivatives in any Banach Space, using the natural generalization: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative

Comment: Have you tried mimicking the proof of the Euclidean case?

Comment: Yes, thats the derivative I meant. But I was wondering if there is a generalization of the statement at the top of my post since there are no partial derivatives in a Banach space.

Comment: I'll take a look at the proof. Thank you for your comments!

Comment: You can define partial derivatives given a basis. Look at the Gateaux derivative in that same article, and let $h$ be one of the basis vectors.

Comment: Yes, it is also clear what the differential should look like once we choose as basis. Looking at the Euclidean case, I'd like to think the continuity of the partial derivatives (with  respect to this basis) should also guarantee that the function is differentiable in the first place.